# Because calendar depends on table_calendar >=2.3.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.17.0, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, calendar, yaml

I have this error while running pubget table_calendar (^3.0.3) in my Calendar app. Here is my pubspec file

```
name: calendar
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  table_calendar: ^3.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
flutter:
uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems weird that you are trying to do a pub get on table_calendar: ^3.0.3 but the error is being thrown trying to get table_calendar >= 2.3.0. I would look around that area.

Comment: I'd appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

1. i am not getting any error , its work totally fine with me with the same packages and sdk
2. you can try changing the sdk version to   sdk: ">=1.17.0 <3.0.0"

```
name: getx_test_1
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  get: ^4.6.1
  table_calendar: ^3.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: I did that but received same error

Comment: but both the solutions working fine with me

Comment: Idk why it's not working. My flutter version is 2.5.3, Dart version 2.14.4